# Interval notation for A-B

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let ℝ be a universal set. Given A = {x ϵ ℝ: 5 < x ≤ 10} and B = {x ϵ ℝ: -5 < x < 6}. Find the interval notation for A-B.

Since ℝ is a universal set, by definition of difference A - B = A ⋂ ~B. Hence, the steps should be:

> A - B = {x ϵ ℝ : 5 < x ≤ 10 ∧ ~(-5 < x < 6)} = {x ϵ ℝ : 5 < x ≤ 10 ∧ -5 ≥ x ≥ 6)} = (5,10) ⋂ [-5,6]

I have worked out the above but it feels totally off, specially for the "negation" part of B which does not seem to make sense. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you should be using

$$\neg\, (-5 \lt x \lt 6) = ((x \le -5) \vee (x \ge 6)) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

instead of what you did of

$$\neg\, (-5 \lt x \lt 6) = (-5 \ge x \ge 6) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note that $\{-5 \ge x \ge 6\}$ has *no* elements as the first condition of $-5 \ge x$ means $x \le -5$, but then you can't also have $x \ge 6$ as well.

Using \eqref{eq1A}, the final result would then instead be

$$A - B  = \{6 \le x \le 10\} = [6,10] \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

I believe you can see this more easily since $A - B$ is the elements of $A$ which are not in $B$, with the overlap between the $2$ sets being $A \cap B = \{5 \lt x \lt 6\} = (5,6)$.

Comment: We're going back and forth here.  Please use the proper symbol $\vee$ instead of $V$ in your first equation.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sorry about that. Thanks for your efforts. I was going to correct that myself when you did that, plus make other changes, but did not notice my changes meant I overrode yours. However, I've now just corrected that issue myself. Also, if you see anything else incorrect, note I don't plan to make any more edits for a while.

Comment: Isn't your first equation wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I believe I am more clear on the negation part. Basically when a range is negated, the opposite will be "the other side of the line" (if you draw the line out). For the final result, since elements of A are not in B in difference, I will basically need to find the part between A and B where it overlap one another? Is it possible to expand the explanation on the (5,6)?

Comment: @JohnOmielan sorry, was thinking about this more. Want to be clear, in difference where A-B, the final results is A which is basically the element of A that is not in B?

Comment: @SunnyBoiz Yes, that's exactly the meaning of $A - B$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork In the first equation, I was using ~ which doesn't display, but I believe the appropriate symbol to use in MathJax is \neg, which I've changed the answer to now, instead of ~, where I used \sim for a while, but that means similar instead, which is not the same thing or the correct symbol.